# How can I set docker volume to directory in another computer? How can I grab data in different computer for jupyter running in docker container?

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, data-transfer

So I have a computer let's call it "local" a laptop that I use to access a host computer behind a VPN at work. Let's call this computer "host". Now, I can setup a jupyter notebook running inside docker on host and access docker container and the jupyter running on host from my local computer as if I'm just running jupyter on local. Now this is the normal common setup.

Question is, I have a computer/database with all the data, let's call it "data_server" that is connected with host through fast ethernet LAN that as the name says, holds all the data I want to work on on host. data_server is just that a linux or BSD server and I can ssh or sftp from host to data_server just fine and perform few commands but it really has no computation capability.

What I want is able to have something like

```
docker run -v data_server/data/I/want : ~/local/workspace/data
```

and work as if the data from the server is part of the volume in docker. Is there a way to do something like this? If not, what is the best practice to access the data on different computer from jupyter running on docker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NFS for that.

You can mount the volume as if it were local, but that folder is on your server.

First you need to set up an NFS server (there are docker images for that if you want)

Then just mount the directory on your client